# Does having more buckets in amazon s3 matter?

Tags: architecture, file-upload, amazon-s3

My website currently has 3 sections in which i want store files, lets call it A, B, and C.  Whats the difference of making my file structure like this:

bucket -> A, B, C

or making the structure like this:

bucket ->A

bucket->B

bucket->C

*consider the A, B, and C as folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine the role of S3 bucket is comparable to that of 'database' (ie, bucket == database). So, would you like to have 3 databases, or just 1? Having them separated may make sense if the data is unrelated and has different usage patterns, but of course it is more complex. So, if you have no particular reason to split your data (like different security requirements), I'd put that into one bucket.